# Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-intent

i have create an **Activity** with 2 seprat **Fragments**. In the *Run Time* the error are these:

Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment    
        android:name="com.example.lesson1.Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/activity_fragment1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.example.lesson1.Fragment2"
        android:id="@+id/activity_fragment2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />


</LinearLayout>

public class Myfragments extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myfragments);

    }
}
```

The errors are :

```
03-26 11:26:27.808: E/Trace(5610): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lesson1/com.example.lesson1.Myfragments}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-26 11:26:31.780: E/AndroidRuntime(5610):     at 
.
.
.
```

Comment: Check you imports once Fragment and FragmentActivity are from the support library or not.

Comment: You extend Activity so you should not have imports from the support library

Comment: @kalyanpvs my adds are import 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment;'

Comment: @Salman that is no nedded `import android.app.Fragment`

Comment: @Salman you need to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity

Comment: @kalyanpvs Thanks, it works but could u tell me why Actvity does not works?

Comment: @Salman see the Raghunandan answer..he is explained..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my adds are import 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment

You extend Normal Activity. So you need to use `import android.app.Fragment`.

If you want to use Fragment from Support Library then extend `FragmentActivity` and use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Fragment Activity is the base class for SupportBased Fragments.